# Webscrape a product website like thingiverse

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am very new in webscraping and I am trying to do a small project where I can scrape a website like Thingiverse or similar where different CAD (or similar) files are shown. I am trying to for a particular Search keyword obtain a list of all the results. When I inspect the website the different products are highlighted in this part of the HTML :

`<div class="SearchResult__searchResultItem--c4VZk">`

However when I go into my script and  type:

29/11 Edited:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urlopen("https://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=vader&type=things&sort=relevant")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

product_list = soup.find_all({ 'class' :'SearchResult__searchResultItem--c4VZk'})
```

I get a 0 sized list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the original question:**

`Class` is passed as a dictionary items. Therefore change code to `soup.find_all('div', { 'class' :'SearchResult__searchResultItem--c4VZk'})`

**This demo BeautifulSoup scraping the html:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="SearchResult__searchResultItem--c4VZk">Test</div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
Result_list = soup.find_all('div', { 'class' :'SearchResult__searchResultItem--c4VZk'})
print(Result_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[<div class="SearchResult__searchResultItem--c4VZk">Test</div>]
```

**For your edited question:**

`BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")` this passes in your response object and not your HTML. The response object will contain HTTP status, headers and all sorts of information. To get the HTML try `html = page.read()`.

The website is loading html tags via JavaScript. Therefore `urllib.request` / `BeautifulSoup` will not be able to extract the data. You can test this by printing out the html using `print(soup.prettify())`. To get around this issue you can use some sort of web automation tool like `selenium`.

Had the website returned the HTML as expected. The scrape code would look something like:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urlopen("https://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=vader&type=things&sort=relevant") as response:
      html = page.read()
      soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
      print(soup.prettify()) # The HTML tag does not appear as it's generate by JavaScript.
      product_list = soup.find_all({ 'class' :'SearchResult__searchResultItem--c4VZk'})
      print(product_list)
```

Comment: I am still having the same problem. I attach full code: ```from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urlopen("https://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=vader&type=things&sort=relevant")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

product_list = soup.find_all({ 'class' :'SearchResult__searchResultItem--c4VZk'})
````